# Unable to download a file after login using python request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download a file using python requests module bu logging in to the site first. I am able to login but when i send a get request to download the file it shows me the login page again.

Code:

```
login_url = 'https://seller.flipkart.com/login'
manifest_url = 'https://seller.flipkart.com/order_management/manifest.pdf'

username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'password'

params = {'sellerId':'seller_id'}
payload = {'authName':'flipkart',
           'username':username,
           'password':password}

ses = requests.Session()
ses.post(login_url, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Connection':'keep-alive'})
response = ses.get(manifest_url, params=params, headers={'Content-Type':'application/pdf','Connection':'keep-alive'})

print response.status_code
print response.url
print response.content
```

On running this code I get the html of login page as content.
I used fiddler and got the below data:

```
Request URL: https://seller.flipkart.com/order_management/manifest.pdf?sellerId=seller_id
Request Method: GET
sellerId: seller_id

# Request Headers

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://seller.flipkart.com/order_management?sellerId=seller_id
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 

# Response Headers

Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 13:12:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 3652
Connection: keep-alive
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; preload
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
X-Req-Id: REQ-14d7434a-e429-40e4-801f-6010d7c0b48c
X-Host-Id: 0008
content-disposition: attachment; filename=Manifest-seller_id-30-Dec-2015-18-42-30.pdf
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

How to download the file ?

Comment: Correct me If i'm wrong. First, you are sending POST request with `ses.post` and GET request with `self.ses.get`. Is this really correct ? I mean shouldn't it be `ses.get` ?

Comment: Sorry, That was a typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `stream=True` and then write the contents to a file.

```
import re 

# Send request by setting 'stream=True'
r = ses.get(manifest_url, ..., stream=True)

# Fetch filename
d = r.headers['content-disposition']
fname = re.findall("filename=(.+)", d)

# Write content to file
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
```

[Docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow).

Comment: It is giving .. `KeyError: content-disposition`. As i have told in my question. When Sending the get request for the file It shows the html in content. shouldn't it directly download the file beacuse i have already logged in using session?